# Setting the state of an entity to Deleted removes the entity from the dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, state, dbcontext

I am relatively new to a Entity Framework. Lately I have come across to this odd behavior (in my mind) that really puzzles me.

Why does tracked entity gets removed from the dbContext if I set it's state to Deleted?

For example:

```
var customers = db.Customers
.Where(customer => customer.FirstName.Contains("John"))
.Take(10)
.ToList();

//Let's iterate through the customers -list
//and remove the 5th customer
int i = 1;
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    if(i == 5)
    {
        //An exception will be thrown
        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    i++;
}
```

When the 5th customer's state is changed from `Unchanged` to `Deleted` the whole object will be destroyed from the context and even from the `customers` -list. And to make things worse: this will also throw an exception, because this action changes the very list we are iterating through!

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening before the changes have been saved to the database by calling `db.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: Because it would be weird to mark an entity as deleted and have it return as the result of a query.

Comment: Please include the details of the exception that's being thrown

Answer (score 6):

> Why does tracked entity gets removed from the dbContext if I set it's state to Deleted?

To prevent something really weird like this...

```
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}

foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm a deleted customer that still exists");
}
```

The fallout from this would force us to write code like this.

```
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    //Extra code to make sure nothing deleted is in here
    if(db.Entry(customer).State != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
       //Do work
    }
}
```

Note that the object still exists in the ObjectStateManager but any normal interaction with the object graph won't yield any deleted objects. You can still see it exists in there like this...

```
var customer = customers.First();
db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(customer).State.ToString()); //Deleted
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I was assuming that when you set an entity's state to Deleted is would mean "marked for deletion" rather than "It is actually now deleted".

PS:

Comment: it's still technically "marked for deletion" by Entity Framework; hence the item is still in the ObjectStateManger.  the dbContext, however, is smart enough to assume that if it is "marked for deletion", you don't actually want to interact with the object anymore.  `SaveChanges()` will actually execute the command to remove the item from storage and from the ObjectStateManager.